# Prove that there exists a bijective mapping $g:A\rightarrow B \;$ so that $g(x)=y$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $f:A\rightarrow B\;$be a bijective mapping, $x$ an element of $A$ and $y$ an element of $B$. Prove that there exists a bijective mapping $g:A\rightarrow B \;$ so that $g(x)=y$.

So the above is the full question and I am frustrated. Could anyone hint me and correct the thoughts below if they are incorrect?

1. If $f:A\rightarrow B\;$ be a bijective mapping, $x$ an element of $A$ and $y$ an element of $B$ then $\exists\, g:A\rightarrow B \;$ such that $g(x)=y$.
2. Prove by contrapositive: If there isn't a $g:A\rightarrow B \;$ such that $g(x)=y \;\forall x \in A \; \forall y \in B$, then there doesn't exist a bijective mapping $f:A\rightarrow B$.

Is proof by contrapositive correct?

If not, may I have some directions?

Hints preferred.

Comment: $g: z\mapsto \begin{cases} y, & z=x, \\ f(x), & z=f^{-1}(y), \\ f(z), & \textrm{otherwise}.\end{cases}$

Comment: @Dong-gyuKim this is correct. However, it should be noted that a consistency check is needed when $x=f^{-1}(y)$.

Comment: I agree, if $x=f^{-1}(y)$ then we are done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not correct. Basically, you are just saying that $\alpha$ implies $\beta$ because if $\beta$ were false, then $\alpha$ would be false too, and nothing else.

Let $z=f(x)$. Let $\varphi\colon B\longrightarrow B$ be that map such that:

- $\varphi(z)=y$;
- $\varphi(y)=z$;
- $\varphi(b)=b$ if $b\in B\setminus\{y,z\}$.

Then $\varphi$ is a bijection. Therefore, $\varphi\circ f$ is a bijection too. But $(\varphi\circ f)(x)=y$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand the way of constructing the new function. The only incomprehensible thing is that what's the purpose of the question? To test whether I could form a new function $\varphi$?

Comment: I assume that the purpose of the question is primarily to test whether you can *properly write down a full proof* that such a function exists (by providing an example *and* proving that the example satisfies the required properties). Learning proper reasoning is likely the main focus of your classes right now.

Answer (score 0):

If we already have $f(x)=y$, then of course $f$ itself would work for $g$. Otherwise, $g$ is obtained by letting $g(x)=y$, $g(f^{-1}(y))=f(x)$, and $g(z)=f(z)$ for $z \notin \{x, f^{-1}(y)\}$.